# Can this if statement be simplified?

Tags: python

I would like to know if the following script can be simplified? Thank you!

```
def charge(atom, r_12):
    #Defining the charge
    if atom == "C":
        E = energy(-4, r_12)
    if atom == "N":
        E = energy(-3, r_12)
    if atom == "Cs" or atom == "H" :
        E = energy(1, r_12)
    if atom == "Ge" or atom == "Pb" or atom == "Si" :
        E = energy(2, r_12)
    if atom == "Br" or atom == "I" :
        E = energy(-1, r_12)
    if atom == "X":
        E = energy(-2, r_12)
    return E
```

The energy(q_ion, r_12) is just another function I defined for calculating the interaction energy and m is the math package in python.

```
def energy(q_ion, r_12):
    #Calculating the energy
    Q = -1
    l = 6
    E = (Q * q_ion * m.erf(r_12 / l)) / r_12
    return E
```

Comment: In the future, please don't use the "snippet" feature for Python. It's intended for HTML/CSS/JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, Since the second argument is same in all the if condition you can declare the value of r_12 in energy and use dict with 'c', 'n' and all other as keys and q_ion as value

Answer (score 2):

I'd simplify and improve this this by both

- keeping the by-atom input in a dictionary, which both

  - makes the collection of possible inputs more manageable
  - avoids successively comparing after a result has already been found (originally, each `if` is discretely checked even when `E` has been named, though this can be fixed by using `elif`!)
- caching the results of the calculations, which will speed up successive requests for the same `(atom, r_12)` pair

```py
from functools import lru_cache

atomic_charge = {
    "C": -4,
    "N": -3,
    ...
}

@lru_cache
def energy(q_ion, r_12):
    #Calculating the energy
    Q = -1
    l = 6
    E = (Q * q_ion * m.erf(r_12 / l)) / r_12
    return E

def charge(atom, r_12):
    return energy(atomic_charge[atom], r_12)
```

Note `KeyError` will be raised for atoms not in your source dict (where your initial version would raise `NameError: E not defined` if no `if` tripped)

[`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) keeps the last N (defaults to 128) results in an internal mapping which can be returned faster if the same input is given for a small overhead, this is known as [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

If repeated requests for the same `(atom, r_12)` pair is unlikely, you can skip the `lru_cache` as it's only adding a small overhead without benefit

---

Finally, if you have a huge number of atoms to process (say >10000, not Avogadro's-sized!), Scipy may have a more direct function you can use with some scientific array, which will be *much* faster after the initial setup pain

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.energy_distance.html

Answer (score 1):

One simplification would be to use a dictionary instead of all the if statements.  If you're going to be calling "charge" a lot, or if this same information is reused elsewhere, you may want to define the dictionary in a broader context (e.g. globally).

```
def charge(atom, r_12):
    charges = {"C": -4, "N": -3, ...}
    return energy(charges[atom], r_12)
```

Comment: This is great and indeed just what they need, but I'd push the dict creation outside of the function so it's not re-created each call!

Comment: I agree.  If this function is going to be called a lot, or if performance matters, then it would be better not to create this dictionary inside of the function.  If those things aren't the case then it may just be a little simpler to create within the function.

Answer (score 0):

**I would create a dictionary.**

```
table = {
    "C": -4,
    "N": -3,
    "Cs": 1,
    "H": 1,
    "Ge": 2,
    "Pb": 2,
    "Si": 2,
    "Br": -1,
    "I": -1,
    "X": -2
}


def charge(atom, r_12):
    return energy(table[atom], r_12)
```

In fact, you can remove the `charge` function altogether and reference the dictionary directly in the `energy` function.

Answer (score 0):

- if you update to Python 3.10 you will be able to use Switch statements, thatskes this kind of if chain much easier.
- Other than that, the if statements where you are iterating over more than one value using "or", should be better if you add those values to a list or tuple (depending on your needs), and then iterate over the list. I've always heard that too many "or" statements are bad practice.
- If you don't want the code to be bloated with the values you could add those to a list and use a for loop to iterate over it, it would look pretty much just as this one, but in case you need to change a value it's gonna be way easier.